# How do I change OutDir variable in Visual C++?

Tags: visual-c++, linker

In the linker the binary destination is specified as:

$(OutDir)\$(ProjectName).exe

I've looked through every setting and I can't see where OutDir is defined. How do I change this?

Answer (score 19):

First option in the "General" section underneath "Configuration Properties".

Answer (score 1):

It's on the very first page of the project properties